# How to spawn new windows on the same (extended) display that they are opened from in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, window

I am working with a second display attached, and I've set it to be an extension of my main display. On the secondary display, I am working with software that opens new windows (in my case, Matlab opens figures when I run my script). These new windows always spawn on the main display. Can I make sure that instead, they always spawn on the same display as where the software is that opened/created them (so on the secondary display in my case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to find a solution for each problematic product.

For Matlab, you can try
[WindowAPI](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437-windowapi),
which adds more functionality for monitor placement (and more).

You may also find a script in the post
[Is it possible to viewing the "figure" window on second display](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16663-is-it-possible-to-viewing-the-figure-window-on-second-display),
for opening figures on the second monitor if available, otherwise on the first monitor.

Comment: I was not aware that I had to look for a solution with Matlab, and not with Windows, so thanks. The WindowAPI seems very useful, I'm playing with it and can move my figures to the desired screen.